# Як сказати "строить глазки" українською мовою?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В російській мові є словосполучення "строить глазки"? А як воно буде українською? Бачила на сайті HowToSay 2 варіанти перекладу: "стріляти очима" та "будувати вічка". Але, як на мене, це не дуже влучно. Можливо, в українській мові є відповідник цьому словосполученню?

Comment: Ми не знаємо і не можемо знати, що́ іноземною мовою означає «строить глазки» або «มองดู». Але ми знаємо, що, за вашим перекладом, воно відповідає словосполученням «стріляти очима». Якщо «стріляти очима» — «не дуже влучно», то у запитанні варто написати більш влучне словосполучення — можливо, не таке лаконічне. Або інше визначення вашими власними словами. Тоді на запитання можна буде відповісти.

Comment: "Стріляти очима" - це дослідний переклад. А я питаю, можливо, в українській мові є відповідник цьому словосполученню. Якщо б я знала "більш влучне словосполучення" - я б не ставила такі питання!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах поряд зі «[стріляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/striljaty) · [очима](http://sum.in.ua/s/oko)» подає такі варіанти:

- *гострити очі* (це означає кидання коротких швидких поглядів, не обов'язково залицяльних);
- *стригти/стригнути оком/очима*;
- *стріляти/стрельнути оком/очима*;
- *стріляти/стрілити поглядом/поглядами*.

У книзі [Вусик О.С. Словник українських синонімів: Понад 1500 синонімічних гнізд / За ред. докт. філолог. наук, проф. А.М.Поповського. — Дніпропетровськ: Січ, 2000. — 424 с.](//books.google.com/books?id=5g4aAQAAIAAJ) наведене ціле гніздо слів і виразів на тему залицянь (як хлопців до дівчат, так і дівчат до хлопців), хоча більшість із них стосуються інших видів/способів залицянь:

> <sub>*ЗАЛИЦЯТИСЯ, амуритися (з ким), амурничати, баламутити (кого), бігати (за ким), ватажитися (залицятися гуртом), видзігорюватися, витися («біля мене хлопці в'ються»), вихилясити, волочитися, воркувати, вчащати (до кого), горнутися, гульвісничати, дженджуритися, донжуанити, жартувати («жартували до зорі»), женихатися, жирувати, загравати, займати («нехай мене той займає, хто кохання в серці має»), іржати, кахикати (він до неї все кахикає), кокетувати, липнути (до кого), лицятися, ловеласити, ловеласничати, малюватися (перед ким), мартоплясити, моргати, набиватися (хитрощами), переморгуватися, піддобрюватися, піддобрятися, підкахикувати, підклинюватися, підкочуватися, підлещуватися, підморгувати, підмощатися, підмощуватися, підсипатися, підсокирюватися, підстрелювати (він за нею підстрелює), підсусіджуватися, покахикувати, прилюбляти, присватуватися, присусіджуватися, увиватися (біля кого), уганяти, уганятися, унаджуватися, упадати, фліртувати,
>
>   *** барвінком під ноги стелитися; бігати цуциком; бути на зальотах; вдаватися до флірту; вертіти хвостом (про жінок); вишкіряти зуби (до кого); вішатися на шию (ж.); гострити очі; грати бровами; грати очима; дух ронити (за ким); завойовувати серце; закручувати голову; закручувати любов; звиватися роєм (гуртом залицятися); зачіпати дівчину (хлопця); кидати гедза; клинці підбивати; клинці тесати; крутити голову; крутити любов; крутити тралі-валі; крутити роман; крутити шури-мури; липнути до жіночих спідниць; липнути шевською смолою; липнути, як шевська смола до кожуха; липнути, як шевська смола до чобота; литки присмалювати (біля кого); литки смалити; ліпити глечик; ліпити макітру; моргати на всі боки; мостом стелитися; м'яти ханьки; накидати оком (початок залицяння); нашіптувати солодкі слова; освідчуватися в коханні; підбивати клина; підбивати клинці; підбивати колодочки; підкочуватися бубликом; підпускати бісики; підпускати гедзиків очима; підпускати кукільмента; підпускати ляси; підпускати москаля (залицятися з обманом); поглядати, як кіт на сало; поглядати, як півень на тік; покоряти серце; пригортатися серцем; присмалювати литки; присмалювати халявки; пробивати дорогу до серця; пробивати стежку до серця; пробивати шлях до серця; прокладати кладку; прясти очима; пускати бісики; пускати гедзики очима; робити очка; робити очки; розводити шашні; розводити шашні-мишашні; розводити шури-мури; розпускати слинки; розпускати пір'я; розпускати хвіст; сокоріти у вічі; співати флейтою; справляти зальоти; справляти фіглі-міглі; стелити містки; стригти очима; стригти очицями; стріляти очима; стріляти очицями; строїти вихиляси та викрутаси; топтати доріжку; топтати слід; топтати сліди; топтати стежечки; туманити голову; утоптувати стежечку до серця; ходити, мов прив'язаний; ходити на прив'язі; ходити тінню; ходити хвостиком; ходити, як кіт біля гарячого вареника; чіплятися на шию; шмилити губки (ж.); шукати дорогу до серця; шукати шлях до серця.*</sub>

*Будувати вічка* мені особисто здається калькою, причому недолугою (можливо, такою, що взагалі з'явилася в результаті роботи Google Translate) — майже немає траплянь у літературі, але ретельно я не досліджував, тож можу серйозно помилятися.

Це є [такі варінти зі словників на сайті R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

- *бі́сики пуска́ти*;
- *бі́сики очи́ма посила́ти*;
- *мані́ритися* (в широкому сенсі);
- *морга́ти на ко́го*;
- *очима грати*;
- *очи́ма пря́сти*.

Comment: I don't know how you've managed to post an answer at the time the question was closed; anyway, you should have not been able to, so I'm deleting the answer. Sorry, it must have been a glitch in SE engine.

Comment: I've been pointed that the SE engine, [indeed, has such function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/187133), so I have no choice but to restore this post. I apologize for inconvenience.

Comment: @bytebuster, дивно, що Ви стільки користуєтеся Stack Exchange і ніколи з цим не стикалися, бо я це «постійно бачу» (ну, принаймні, стикався неодноразово, хоч скільки раз — точно не знаю). У закритих запитаннях відповіді ще й редагувати можна.

Comment: Власні відповіді ви можете редагувати, навіть допоки вони знаходяться у видаленому стані. На це є причини: це є підготовка до відновлення допису (раніше видаленого), і вона може здійснюватися у кілька етапів. Це зовсім не те саме, як публікація відповіді на щойно закрите запитання. Як ви могли прочитати за посиланням на Meta.SE, клієнтський скрипт малює гарний warning і дізейбить кнопку «Опублікувати». Але користувач на своєму боці може заблокувати такий скрипт, і попередження не буде надіслано. У таких випадках помилку мав видати серверний скрипт, але потім ця вимога була послаблена.

Comment: І, як я вже писав у чаті, мене найбільш бентежить те, що деякі користувачі революціонують видалення запізнілої відповіді на погане запитання і докладають *precisely zero effort* до порятунку самого поганого запитання, яке рано чи пізно буде видалене, якщо не буде врятоване кимось.

Comment: @bytebuster, у фінальному результаті добрими є ті запитання, що генерують якісний контент :).

Comment: Це цікаве означення, і якщо його розвинути і обґрунтувати, можливо, можна спробувати просунути його [батькам-засновникам](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).